# "Proper Branch Cuts" in A Physical Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, complex-numbers

I am solving the following acoustic problem.

> [image]
>
> Consider a two-dimensional duct bounded by two parallel walls
> separated by a height of $H$ as shown. The duct is filled with air. A
> vibrating piston(microphone) of length $2L$ is installed on the top
> wall. The piston oscillates simple harmonically with a vertical
> velocity $v=\epsilon\sin{\omega t}$ where $\omega$ is the angular
> frequency, $t$ is time and $\epsilon$ is a small amplitude.

In above situation, velocity in $y$ direction ($v$) satisfies the following boundary value problem.

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}\tag{1}$

$\displaystyle y=0, v=0 \tag*{(2)}$

$\displaystyle y=H, v=\begin{cases} 0 & x<-L, \\ \epsilon\sin{\omega t} &-L<x<L \\ 0 & x>L\end{cases}\tag{3}$

My goal is to state $v(x,y,t)$ as a Fourier inverse transform(and evaluate the integral, but that is for
[another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415907/evaluate-int-infty-infty-frac-sinh-lefty-sqrt-alpha2-omega2-righ)). In addition, the problem states

> You must insert **proper branch cuts** and show them clearly in the
> complex plane together with the inverse transform contour.

**My Attempt**

As a hint, I was asked to perform the separation of variable $v=V(x,y)\sin{\omega t}$. Applying this to (1), we obtain

$-\omega^2 V= V_{xx} + V_{yy}\tag*{}$

Since the domain of $x$ is $-\infty < x< \infty$, we apply the Fourier transform defined by $\tilde{V}(\alpha, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}V(x,y)e^{-i\alpha x}dx$ and obtain

$-\omega^2 \tilde{V} = -\alpha^2 \tilde{V} + \tilde{V}_{yy} \tag*{}$

This simplifies to

$\tilde{V}_{yy} = (\alpha^2-\omega^2)\tilde{V} \tag*{}$

And the general solution to this equation is

$\tilde{V} = A(\alpha)e^{Ky} + B(\alpha)e^{-Ky}\tag*{}$

where $K(\alpha) = (\alpha^2-\omega^2)^{1/2}$ and $A,B$ are arbitrary functions.

Since $K$ has branch points at $\alpha=\pm\omega$, we will insert branch cuts.

**Now, this is the point I don't understand.** What does "proper branch cuts" mean in this problem? My understanding is that, we need to take branch cuts that makes the solution bounded since we don't want unbounded solution in physical problems. However, the domain of $y$ is $[0,H]$ which is a bounded domain. So, $\tilde{V}$ would be automatically bounded, wouldn't it? So I don't understand what "proper" means in this context.

Comment: It might mean unbounded *in time* (i.e., exponentially growing solutions as a function of *time*). I gather that this is what it means because the branch cuts are in *frequency space*, which is related to the time-dependence of the problem, not the spatial dependence.